# Best Way to sort and / or display a multidimmentionnel array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional array toto, the elements of this array are interconnected by "conx" property.
So I have a multidimensional array

```
$toto=
array(
"A"=>array(id=>"A",conx=>"E,C"),
"B"=>array(id=>"B",conx=>"C,F"),
"C"=>array(id=>"C",conx=>"A,B"),
"D"=>array(id=>"D",conx=>""),
"E"=>array(id=>"E",conx=>"A"),
"F"=>array(id=>"F",conx=>"B"),
...
)
```

I am trying to break it into an array grouped/indexed and display it like:

```html
*[A]<br>
----*[C]<br>
-------- *[B]<br>
------------*[F]<br>
----*[E]<br>
*[D]<br>
etc...
```

Is there a built in function in php to do this or some best practice way of doing this?

Comment: What are the rules for showing the array in the way you did? Why is C listed after A instead of B? Without the explicit rules, it is not possible to write a program to do it.

Comment: what exactly your output be ?

Comment: Please show us thet you tried to solve that pb. Show us your php code, and we may help.

Comment: @kainaw I'm sorry about that. there was an error in the array I fix it. 
it is more logical right now. thanks